# Assigning Complex Values to an Int Array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, complex-numbers

everyone. I want to create a random array with a size of `1x1000` and it will have random integers from `0 to 3`. Then I want to assign those numbers in different locations in a 2-D cartesian plane. I use real and imaginary axis as my x and y axis. When I try to assign it to `1j` or `-1j` I have an error message:

> TypeError("can't convert complex to float")

Can you help me please?

```
import numpy as np
from math import *

M = 4
N = 1000

firstsymbols = np.random.randint(M, size=N)
symbols = np.zeros(N)

for i in range(1,N):
    if (firstsymbols[i] == 0):
       symbols[i] = 1
    elif (firstsymbols[i] == 1):
       symbols[i] = 1j
    elif (firstsymbols[i] == 2):
       symbols[i] = -1
    else:
       symbols[i] = -1j

print(symbols)
```

Comment: The problem is you have an NumPy array of dtype float; you're trying to assign a complex number into a "slot" that can only take floats.

Comment: All you need to do is use a complex rather that float dtype when creating your array with `zeros`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `numpy` array of complex numbers with `broadcasting`,

```
1j * np.arange(10)
```

Or you can keep a 2D array where the first column is the real part and the second column is the imaginary part.

Comment: I divided symbols into real and imaginary matrices. It works when I combine them